# How to search through nested element values in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I go through an xml file.This is a sample of it.

```
<Cproducts>
   <ID>id_one</ID>
   <Name>name_one</Name>
   <Availability>
        <Departure>
          <Date>2015-12-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
        </Departure>
        <Departure>
          <Date>2015-12-06T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
        </Departure>
    <Availability>
    <ID>id_two</ID>
   <Name>name_two</Name>
   <Availability>
        <Departure>
          <Date>2015-12-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
        </Departure>
        <Departure>
          <Date>2015-12-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
        </Departure>
        <Departure>
          <Date>2015-12-07T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
        </Departure>
        <Departure>
          <Date>2015-12-08T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
        </Departure>
    <Availability>
 </Cproducts>
```

I search through name directly like this.

```
 var getneededData = rootele.Elements("CruiseProduct")
                                .Where(l => l.Element("Name").Value == "some value");
```

then `getneededData` gives only the data where `Name == "some value"`. I want to go through the dates also where `Date ="some date"`. how can I do that directly like for `Name`?

Comment: Do you want to do it in the same ´Where´ clause, for example, where name equals to `some name` AND equals to `some date`. Or maybe you want to find all `CruiseProduct` elements which contain `some date`?

Comment: Have you tryed something similiar: var query = rootele.Descendants("Departure")
               .Where(x => ((DateTime) x.Element("Date")).Year == 1998 && ((DateTime) x.Element("Date")).Month == 2)
               .ToList();

Comment: Yes I want to do it in the same Where clause @Sergii

Answer (score 0):

Just add an  or condition including `date` element

```
var anotherDate = DateTime.Now ; 
var getneededData = rootele.Elements("CruiseProduct")
           .Where(l => l.Element("Name").Value == "some value" || DateTime.ParseExact(l.Descendants("Date").First().Value, "o") == anotherDate);
```

Comment: this is okay,but this  goes  only through first element in each "Availability" and I want to go through all dates

Comment: What kind of condition would you apply on the list of dates ?

Comment: I want to check the availability of requested date by checking all the dates. (name and other two stuffs also like this.). then , should return Information according to the requested date,name and etc ....

Answer (score 0):

Your `XML` doesn't match with your code. I'm assuming your `XML` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Cproducts>
    <CruiseProduct>
        <ID>id_one</ID>
        <Name>name_one</Name>
        <Availability>
            <Departure>
                <Date>2015-12-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
            </Departure>
            <Departure>
                <Date>2015-12-06T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
            </Departure>
        </Availability>
    </CruiseProduct>
    <CruiseProduct>
        <ID>id_two</ID>
        <Name>name_two</Name>
        <Availability>
            <Departure>
                <Date>2015-12-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
            </Departure>
            <Departure>
                <Date>2015-12-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
            </Departure>
            <Departure>
                <Date>2015-12-07T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
            </Departure>
            <Departure>
                <Date>2015-12-08T00:00:00.0000000+00:00</Date>
            </Departure>
        </Availability>
    </CruiseProduct>
</Cproducts>
```

Assuming that, you can find a product with "Name" as

```
var name_one_product = xDoc.Descendants("CruiseProduct")
                           .Where(cp => cp.Element("Name").Value == "name_one");
```

And with "Date" as

```
var date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 7);
var product_2015_12_07 = xDoc.Descendants("CruiseProduct")
                             .Where(cp => cp.Descendants("Date")
                                            .Any(d => DateTime.Parse(d.Value).Date.Equals(date.Date)));
```

And if you want both the conditions, then

```
var date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 7); //the date on which you want to filter
var product_2015_12_07 = xDoc.Descendants("CruiseProduct")
                                .Where(cp => cp.Element("Name").Value == "name_one" ||
                                             cp.Descendants("Date")
                                               .Any(d => DateTime.Parse(d.Value).Date.Equals(date.Date)));
```

use `||` or `&&` whichever serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and this works for me....

```
 var getneededData = rootele.Elements("CruiseProduct")
                                .Where(l => l.Element("Location").Value == "some destination" && l.Element("Types").Element("Type").Value == "some type" && l.Descendants("Date").Any(d=> d.Value.Substring(0,10).Equals("some date")));
```